# UWP (Windows 10) uploading/download files to server

Tags: c#, ftp, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm working on a simple HTML editor with ability to upload files directly on server. I know how to accomplish that in a forms application, but I really wish to create Universal app for windows 10. So my question is, does anyone know how to upload/download files in UWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using UWP, if you are uploading/downloading files directly to/from a networked server IP you can use the [BackgroundTransfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212018.aspx) Classes.  If you are attempting to upload/download to/from a URL, you will want to use the [HttpClient](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient) Class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply. I think  BackgroundTransfer should work, but do you have and idea if its possible to upload files via FTP credentials there? Thanks for your time

Comment: BackgroundTransfer does support downloads from FTP sites, but, for UWP, you will have to manually open sockets to upload to an FTP.  Check out [link](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/ftp-endeavor-in-winrt-i/)[/link] for more info on how best to accomplish that.